# List of characters (escape sequences in string literals) used by python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Like given character what are the other character used by python.

```
   \ is an escape character in Python

   \t gets interpreted as a tab
```

When I opened the file `test_file=open('c:\Python27\test.txt','r')`. It gave error as `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\Python27\test.txt'`. When I did google search I got to know `\t` interpreted as tab in python. Like wise any other character which is reserved by python for specific use

Comment: What do you mean by *other character used by python*?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: When I opened the file test_file=open('c:\Python27\test.txt','r') . It gave error as IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\Python27\test.txt'. When I did google search I got to know \t interpreted as tab in python. Like wise any other character which is reserved by python for specific use

Comment: use raw string literals for Windows paths: `r'c:\..\test.txt'` (notice `r''`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a backslash mean in a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580002/what-does-a-backslash-mean-in-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [String literals section in Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) suggested [by @Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671613/list-of-characters-escape-sequences-in-string-literals-used-by-python#comment57088582_34671613):

> Unless an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, escape sequences in
>   strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by
>   Standard C.  The recognized escape sequences are:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| Escape Sequence | Meaning                         |
+=================+=================================+
| ``\newline``    | Ignored                         |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\\``          | Backslash (``\``)               |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\'``          | Single quote (``'``)            |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\"``          | Double quote (``"``)            |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\a``          | ASCII Bell (BEL)                |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\b``          | ASCII Backspace (BS)            |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\f``          | ASCII Formfeed (FF)             |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\n``          | ASCII Linefeed (LF)             |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\N{name}``    | Character named *name* in the   |
|                 | Unicode database (Unicode only) |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\r``          | ASCII Carriage Return (CR)      |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\t``          | ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)      |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\uxxxx``      | Character with 16-bit hex value |
|                 | *xxxx* (Unicode only)           |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\Uxxxxxxxx``  | Character with 32-bit hex value |
|                 | *xxxxxxxx* (Unicode only)       |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\v``          | ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)         |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\ooo``        | Character with octal value      |
|                 | *ooo*                           |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| ``\xhh``        | Character with hex value *hh*   |
+-----------------+---------------------------------+
```